# Grails Creating JSON format output

Tags: json, grails

I'm writing a Grails web app to take the input data below and reformat it into the output format below that then can be used to draw fancyTree view. I created a controller class with the code shown in the except that follows. 
How can I iterate through to make the format like the output format shown below?  I looked at how Groovy does each syntax but how can I use it to add ingredients?

**code excerpt:**

```
def list(){

    def results = recipies.list()

    def recipiesContents = [:] //Test List

    recipiesContents=[] 

    for (record in results){
        test.add([folder:true, title: results.Name, key: results.key
        ])
    }


    //render response types
    withFormat {
        html test
        json {render test as JSON}
        xml {render test as XML}
    }
}
```

**Input data:**

```
{
recipies :[

{key: "1",
category:"Tuna Sandwich"
data:[{some data}],
ingredients: [
    {item_name:"mayo",
      brand: "My Own Brand"
    },
    {
      item_name: "Tuna".
      brand: "Bumble Bee"
    }
]},
{key: "2",
category:"Chicken Noodle Soup"
data:[{some data}],
ingredients: [
    {item_name:"condensed chicken soup",
      brand: "Campbell"
    },
    {
      item_name: "Noodles".
      brand: "Top Ramen"
    }
]}

]
}
```

**output data:**

```
[
{
    title: "Tuna Sandwich"
    ingredients: [
        {title: "Tuna"},
        {title: "mayo"}
    ]
},
{
    title: "Chicken Noodle Soup",
    ingredients: [
        {title: "condensed chicken soup"},
        {title: "Noodles"}
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
for (record in results){
    def ingredients = [:]
    for (ingredient in record.ingredients) {
        ingredients.add([title: ingredient.item_name)
    }
    test.add([title: results.category, ingredients: ingredients
    ])
}
```